# What does this match : bash regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

```
if [[ "$len" -lt "$MINLEN" && "$line" =~ \[*\.\] ]]
```

This is from Advanced bash scripting guide "Example 10-1. Inserting a blank line between paragraphs in a text file"

As I understand this matches "any string or a dot character". Right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matches zero or more open bracket characters (`\[*`), followed by a period and a close square bracket (`\.\]`).  Note that it only requires that a match exist somewhere in "$line", not that the whole string match.  Here's a demo:

```
$ showmatch() { [[ "$1" =~ \[*\.\] ]] && echo "matched: '${BASH_REMATCH[0]}'" || echo "no match"; }
$ showmatch "abc[.]def"
matched: '[.]'
$ showmatch "abc.]def"
matched: '.]'
$ showmatch "abc[[[[[[[.]def"
matched: '[[[[[[[.]'
$ showmatch "abc[[[[[[[xyz.]def"
matched: '.]'
$ showmatch "abc[[[[[[[.xyz]def"
no match
```

...and I'm pretty sure that's not what it's supposed to be doing in that example script.

Comment: I agree "I'm pretty sure that's not what it's supposed to be doing in that example script." I think the example is on an older version of bash.

Answer (score 2):

It means any string ended with dot inside bracers, for example:

```
[.]
[abc.]
```

Comment: I don't think this is a valid answer in light of answers by Gordon and Fred. But for the example in ABS the regex should match any string of characters ending in a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Update: +1 to Gordon Davisson, who has summed it up pretty well... so I've redacted my original post

In brief: You can test the result of a bash regex match like this:

```
[[ "[*.]" =~ \[*\.\] ]] ; echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```